# Android Application is not crashing in emulator 2.3.3 but crash in device 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a app which was working properly on device Android 2.3.3.
But is not working properly on Android 4.0.3 device.

Errors are
App crash at start.
Grid-view icon not clickable after clicked once. Works again on restart for once.

These are examples.
These are platform issues are just coding errors.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Try to get hold of the logcat output and post it here.

Comment: Crashing in emulator 2.3.3 but crash in device 4.0.3, Is it crashing on emulator 4.0.3? Test it. And you have to know that crash may be for Particular device. It happens on Android :(

Comment: I have just checked. on emulator and device 4.0.3 grid view is not working after once but in emulator 2.3.3, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782601/location-manager-not-working-in-android-4-0-2-emulator). Try not using the Deprecated methods/API(in your case GRIDVIEW) in your code because Android API does not support the deprecated methods/API in the latest versions.